# Problemas para iniciar sesión con facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api

he estado tratando de publicar en facebook desde una web (estoy haciendo pruebas). El problema es cuando intento iniciar sesión me arroja el siguiente mensaje:
[image: error login]

Este es mi archivo index.php

```
<?php
// Include FB configuration file
require_once 'fbConfig.php';

if(isset($accessToken)){
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }else{
        // Put short-lived access token in session
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
        
        // OAuth 2.0 client handler helps to manage access tokens
        $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
        
        // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
        $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
        $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $longLivedAccessToken;
        
        // Set default access token to be used in script
        $fb->setDefaultAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);
    }
    
    //FB post content
    $message = 'Test from website';
    $title = 'Post From Website';
    $link = 'http://www.algunaUrlParaRedireccionarEnElPost.com/';
    $description = 'Test';
    $picture = 'https://slp-statics.astockcdn.net/static_assets/staging/21fall/homepage/curated-asset-collection/card-2.jpg?width=580';
            
    $attachment = array(
        'message' => $message,
        'name' => $title,
        'link' => $link,
        'description' => $description,
        'picture'=>$picture,
    );
    
    try{
        // Post to Facebook
        $fb->post('/me/feed', $attachment, $accessToken);
        
        // Display post submission status
        echo 'The post was published successfully to the Facebook timeline.';
    }catch(FacebookResponseException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(FacebookSDKException $e){
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
}else{
    // Get Facebook login URL
    $fbLoginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $fbPermissions);
    
    // Redirect to Facebook login page
    echo '<a href="'.$fbLoginURL.'"><img src="fb-btn.png" /></a>';
}
```

Este es mi archivo de configuracion del sdk de facebook(config.php);

```
<?php
if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

// Include the autoloader provided in the SDK
require_once __DIR__ . '/php-graph-sdk-5.x/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

// Include required libraries
use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException;
use Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException;

/*
 * Configuration and setup Facebook SDK
 */
$appId         = 'algunID'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret     = 'algunaAppSecret'; //Facebook App Secret
$redirectURL   = 'http://localhost:8077/fbPost/'; //Callback URL
$fbPermissions = array('publish_actions'); //Facebook permission

$fb = new Facebook(array(
    'app_id' => $appId,
    'app_secret' => $appSecret,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
));

// Get redirect login helper
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

// Try to get access token
try {
    if(isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])){
        $accessToken = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];
    }else{
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    }
} catch(FacebookResponseException $e) {
     echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
} catch(FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
}
?>
```

Para usar el SDK lo descargué y lo adjunté en la carpeta fuente donde están todos los archivos que se usarán
.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve investigando acerca de este problema y la mayoria lo soluciona agregando su dominio en la configuracion de su app en facebookDevelopers, pero al ser un ambiente local no me permite hacerlo.